# Why is simple Angular App image not running locally using Docker?

Tags: angular, docker

I'm new to Docker and am trying to run locally the Angular default app on a Docker container.

After creating the App with `ng new`, I added the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
```

Then I make the build:
`$ docker build -t testimage .`

Finally, I try to run it on the bash with
`$ docker run -p 3000:80 --rm testimage`

and I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint modest_chaplygin (df9f0c4b653796c3e9f48e9d4fb155565a61c753b3845dc04decfafbfe709b0e): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3000:tcp:172.17.0.2:80: input/output error.
```

I've tried to the following steps to no avail:
1) restarted computer
2) looked for ports that could be in use but found none with `$ netstat -ano|find ":3000"`
3) still, changed the ports
4) read that this problem could be solved by restarting a docker container, but in this case I have none yet running

Comment: Have you gone through this https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573 something might help.

Comment: Thanks @mchawre for the link. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the thread https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573

One has to restart Docker Desktop to make it work. Right click on the Docker icon below and press restart. This is different from restarting a container.[Check the desktop image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbmAW.png)